# Get the result of setImageResource from random and set it to string

Tags: android

I am a newbie on creating an android application and also in java programming. The following codes are from the tutorials i've watched.

So in my untimed.xml I have 16 ImageButton and 1 TextView and a scrollview with a listview inside.
So each ImgBtn has its id = Button1, Button2 ... textView id is textHere.
In my Untimed.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Untimed extends Activity{

String hello;
TextView text;
ImageButton image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.untimed);

final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);

final ImageButton image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
final ImageButton image2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
final ImageButton image3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
final ImageButton image4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
final ImageButton image5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
final ImageButton image6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
final ImageButton image7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
final ImageButton image8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
final ImageButton image9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
final ImageButton image10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
final ImageButton image11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
final ImageButton image12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button12);
final ImageButton image13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button13);
final ImageButton image14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button14);
final ImageButton image15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button15);
final ImageButton image16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button16);

final int[] myPics = { R.drawable.lettera, R.drawable.letterb, R.drawable.letterc, R.drawable.lettere,R.drawable.letteri, R.drawable.lettero, R.drawable.letteru, R.drawable.letterd, R.drawable.letterf, R.drawable.letterg,R.drawable.letterh, R.drawable.letterj, R.drawable.letterk, R.drawable.letterl, R.drawable.letterm, R.drawable.lettern,R.drawable.letterp, R.drawable.letterq, R.drawable.letterqu, R.drawable.letterr, R.drawable.letters, R.drawable.lettert, R.drawable.letterv,R.drawable.letterw, R.drawable.letterx, R.drawable.lettery, R.drawable.letterz };

int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);

int rando1 = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
image2.setImageResource(myPics[rando1]); (... to image16)   


image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.lettera))){
hello = "A";
text.setText(hello);
}
else{
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.letterb))){
hello = "B";
text.setText(hello);
}
else{
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.letterc))){
hello = "C";
text.setText(hello);
}
else{ .......(same codes for the rest)
}});
}

// I created this method because there are errors in getResources in the above codes.
protected Object getResources(int letterz) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

The code is working (I think) because whenever i click the first image, the textview shows "A" and only letter A.
I want it to show the exact value. like if the image shown is letter F then the textview should also equals to letter F.

PLEASE HELP.:(

Comment: oh, you should have a look at gridview/listview, this is too much code for such a simple need

Comment: I tried using gridview before using this one. but i dont know how to populate it with image.

Comment: @A.S. any suggestions about my problem? I can't find any tutorial about this. I really need help.

Comment: have a look at this one: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

Comment: About public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.lettera))){
hello = "A";
text.setText(hello);
}
else{
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.letterb))){
hello = "B";
text.setText(hello);
} ...

Comment: You populate a Gridview by simply adding ImageViews before closing the Gridview.

Comment: @tehCoder what about image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
if (!image1.equals(getResources(R.drawable.lettera))){
hello = "A";
text.setText(hello);
}

Comment: @A.S.I am using a random (?) 

image.int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);

how can I get the result of rando and display a string = to the viewed/setImageResource?

Comment: @TehCoder I am using a random (?) 

image.int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);

how can I get the result of rando and display a string = to the viewed/setImageResource?

Comment: what do you mean result of `rando`? As soon as you define it, a number is already assigned.

Comment: @TehCoder rando for random. i've seen it on on one of the tutorials . each button is assigned with that "rando" like image1 = rando and image2 is rando1. for them to randomize image (itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with only one image view and that too with static id, not randomly generated. But this should work for you,

Set these for all 16 ImageButton of yours, the idea is to use setId,

```
    image1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
    image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner); // Set myCommoClickListner for all 16
    int rando = (int)(Math.random()* 27);
    image1.setImageResource(myPics[rando]);
    image1.setId(myPics[rando1]); // set id immediate after image button resource is set
```

Now in your CommoClickListner put your logic of settext, by matching getId from view,

```
            OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          Log.i(TAG, "arg0.getTag().toString() = " + arg0.getTag().toString());
                Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.lettera){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
                   generatedString = generatedString+ "A"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
                    text.setText(generatedString);
                }
            }
        };
```

**EDIT :**

Declare   `String generatedString = ""; in your class;

then I have made changes in on click.

Comment: hi ! :) I am having an error on TAG. I created a local variable (as one of the suggestions given). Is it right? The code is working but only for imagebutton1 :( i've done what you said but it only works at button1 :(

Comment: Yes TAG is just local variable. Have you put image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner); and image1.setId(myPics[THIS SHOULD BE AS PER YOUR RANDOM NUMBER]); for all your ImageButtons.

Comment: oh. i'm sorry i didn't change that part X( IT'S WORKING :D thank you very much :))) but can I ask one last thing. How can i "add" those string to each other in using the same textview?

Comment: You mean to say according to user click you want to generate String?

Comment: yes. ilke for example. i clicked button A and B. how can I add the 2 strings on 1 textview only?

Comment: I have updated in answer, about your new requirement see if this works.

Comment: Have you put text.setText("generatedString"); like this? 
Then remove those quote marks.

Comment: Request you to mark this as answer, please ,, if this helps you.. :)

Comment: I am having a problem AGAIN. after successfully putting the above codes, my CountDownTimer isn't working at all :( why is that? @Chitrang

Comment: where is your CountDownTimer ? Please mention in code.

Comment: here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245375/having-trouble-with-multiple-onclicklistener